# An example of abelian ring which is NOT square-free.

Tags: modules, examples-counterexamples

Recall that a ring $R$ is **abelian** if all idempotents are central.

Recall that a right module $M_R$ is called **square-free** if whenever $A$ and $B$ are submodules of $M$ with $A\cong B$ and $A\cap B=0$ then $A=B=0$. The ring $R$ is **square-free** if $R_R$ is square-free.

My question is: Is there an example of an abelian ring which is **NOT** square-free?.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $R=F_2[x,y]/(x,y)^2$ where $F_2$ is the field of two elements.

This ring is local and Artinian, and it has a nonzero socle made up of a direct sum of two copies of the simple module $R/(x,y)$.  This socle witnesses that $R_R$ is not square-free.

Comment: When i saw the question, I immediately knew that a local ring with nonzero nonsimple socle would suffice. So [that's the DaRT query I ran](https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=1&H=23&H=100l&L=98l).

Comment: Thanks alot. Excuse me, I have another question if you don't mind. I registered on the site. Now, I need an abelian $CS$-ring which is NOT square-free. The two keywords "abelian" and "$CS$" already exist in the dropdown menu. But what is the alternative for the square-freeness?.

Comment: @HusseinEid As you saw above, squarefreeness is not a direct option: i had to get around this.  [Here's the same query with CS added](https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=1&H=110l&H=23&H=100l&L=98l) but none of the hits are positive. Maybe these can be ruled out, maybe not, but it's a place to start.

Comment: I think the main problem will be that many rings may not have the CS property decided on them yet!